# Why did Rose not know Where Berta Lived?

Tags: character, two-and-a-half-men

In S01E04, Berta the housekeeper angrily leaves Charlie because his annoying Brother Alan is living with him now. Of course Charlie and Berta are used to  each other's specific habits and a change in living arrangements meant Berta saying goodbye.

Charlie is now furious at Alan, so Alan decides to ask Berta to come back. But Charlie has no clue where Berta lives; he is only able to recall that

> After she works here in the morning, she cleans some rock star's house.

And then comes Rose, the sweet creepy stalker of Charlie who knows *exactly* where Berta works: Steven Tyler from Aerosmith.

The kind of stalker Rose is, she keeps track of everything happening at Charlie's house, even comes at midnight simply because she saw 'the lights coming on' and often reaches Charlie's bedroom/garage etc. She also knew exactly where Berta goes from here.

**Did Rose not know where Berta lived?** Considering the characteristics and habits of Rose, it is very unlikely for her to not know that. She time and again proves she knows everything happening at Halper's.

And if she knew, did she not tell on purpose to Alan & Charlie just to mess with them? Once again it seems very uncharacteristic of her sweet/helping nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TVTropes has a [Rule Of Funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)

> *The limit of the **Willing Suspension of Disbelief** for a given element is directly 
>   proportional to its funniness.*
>
> Any violation of continuity, logic, physics, or common sense is permissible if the result gets enough of a laugh.
>
> This is the comedy equivalent of the Rule of Cool, and is accordingly weighted more in comedy shows. Especially easy to invoke in humor-based American animation and webcomics, where people expect the lack of realism in the art to translate to other areas.

I personally would question why she would want to know where Berta works after Charlie's house but, presumably, that's the funny part and where her interest ends.  Rose is more obsessed with Charlie than Berta so I don't imagine she would follow her all the way home.

Agreed, if she knew where Berta lived, she would have shared the information with Charlie and Alan